# People around a circular table problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

**Problem:**
*15 people, each from different countries, sit around a circular table. What is the probability that a British and a French representative sits next to each other but an American and a Russian representative doesn't.*

The correct solution for this problem is  $\frac{11}{91}$.

I know that all the different variations are $\frac{15!}{15} = 87\ 178\ 291\ 200$, but how can I count all the arrangements that satisfy the given conditions?

Comment: Seat the British and French representatives next to one another.  Then the problem is reduced to the probability that the American and Russian don't sit next to one another in a line of $13$ people.  So, you have two events whose probabilities you need to work out.

Comment: So if I seat first British and French next to one another, I have $15*2$ alternatives. Then I seat an American and a Russian so that they don't sit next to each other in a line of $13$ people, I have $(13*10+2)*11!$ alternatives. Combined I have $15*2*(13*10+2)*11!$ alternatives. I don't get the right result. What I am missing here?

Comment: The probability that the British and French ambassadors sit next to one another is $1/7$ isn't it?  Wherever the British ambassador sits, there are $2$ out of $14$ places the French ambassador can sit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the English and the French representatives as a single individual.  Basically, we are seating $14$ individuals in a way that the American and the Russian do not get close to one another, lest they fight.  Fix a seat for the American.  Then, there are $11$ possible seats for the Russian.  Now, for the remaining $12$ individuals, there are $12!$ ways to arrange them.  Finally, we de-cluster the English and the French, and there are $2!=2$ ways to permute them.  Hence, there are in total $$11\cdot 12!\cdot 2$$
ways to arrange the $15$ people according to the rules.

Now, there are $(15-1)!=14!$ arrangements without care to the seating rules.  Thus, the probability that a random seat assignment will be satisfactory is
$$\frac{ 11\cdot 12!\cdot2}{14!}=\frac{11}{7\cdot 13}=\frac{11}{91}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $14!$ ways to sit the $15$ people with no constraints.

There are $2\cdot 13!$ to seat the table with the Brit and the Frenchman next to each other.

There are $4\cdot 12!$ to seat the table with the Brit and the Frenchman next to each other and the American and the Russian next to each other.

$\frac {2\cdot 13! - \frac 4\cdot 12!}{14!}\\
\frac {2\cdot 13 - 4}{14\cdot 13}\\
\frac {11}{91}$